# Karma Angular - Cannot Find Name 'X'

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm getting a load of errors when I run `Karma Start` in my angular project.

All the errors say: 'Cannot find name Blob', 'Cannot Find name KeyboardEvent', 'Cannot find name HTMLElement', etc.

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/"
    ],
    "types": [
        "jasmine",
        "node",
        "core-js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Help!

Answer (score 1):

adding "dom" to lib in tsconfig.app.json fixed it