# Cannot find name 'DebugElement'

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

When running my tests with `ng test` I'm getting this error:

> ERROR in C:/.../src/app/my/my.component.spec.ts (111,27): Cannot find name 'DebugElement'.

In other SO posts (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836611/karma-angular-cannot-find-name-x)) the recommended solution is adding `"lib": ["dom"]` to the `compilerOptions` in the `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json` files, but for me that solution is not working, I already have `"dom"` in the `"lib"` array as you can see here:

## tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

## tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

The line where the error occurs is the first one of this function:

```js
export function click(el: DebugElement | HTMLElement, eventObj: any = ButtonClickEvents.left): void {
    if (el instanceof HTMLElement) {
        el.click();
    } else {
        el.triggerEventHandler('click', eventObj);
    }
}
```

What else can I be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

import it from the `angular/core` as

```
import { DebugElement } from "@angular/core";
```